# Manipulate String by inserting at index

Tags: java, string

I have a String:

```
C6H14
```

What I want it to be is:

```
C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>14</sub>
```

So basically I want to add `<sub>` before a number and `</sub>` after a number. How can I accomplish this? Keep in mind that the String can be indefinitely long:

```
X4Y6Z10W4T12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a java expert, but I'm pretty sure, you can use regular expressions replace function, where the pattern will be:

```
(\d+)
```

and replacement string will be:

```
<sub>$1</sub>
```

Sorry I'm not 100% sure about the java syntax, but it can be something like:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "<sub>$1</sub>");
```

This method was added in Java 5

here are some more information about regexp in java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

http://javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `Matcher` for that:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb,"<sub>$0</sub>");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String newString = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to construct a new String object for this - there is no way to change a String "in place" (Strings are immutable)

`String.replaceAll` will do this for you.

```
str = str.replaceAll( "\\d+", "<sub>$0</sub>" );
```

is all you need

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.String`s are immutable in Java, so you need to build a new String instance. You have to parse the original string (e.g. using regexes) for that. [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is a good utility for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Matcher and Pattern classes with searching for pattern:
`"\\d+"`

After that, find starting and ending indexes and add `<sub>` and ''

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable, so we cant insert the sub tags in the existing string. So you would need a method that creates a new string. You could use regex, or use a string builder to generate a new string like this:

```
public String parseString(String input) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String format = "<sub>%c</sub>";
        for(char c:input.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                builder.append(String.format(format, c));
            } else {
                builder.append(c);
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```